# XML layout not working as defined

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I design a layout in which there are 2 linear layout whose weightage are 50% and 50%.Instead showing in equal part.First part is showing in almost 70% and second part is only showing in 30% (attached photo).Can u look at it and whats is the problem with the code.

```
![<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="25dp"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
                android:padding="5dp" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etFillPNR"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Please Enter 10 Digit PNR Number"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textSize="20dp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bCross"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cross" />
            </FrameLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                android:weightSum="100"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bGETPNR"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="40"
                    android:text="GetPNR" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bSavePNR"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                    android:layout_weight="40"
                    android:text="Save" />
            </LinearLayout>



        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:orientation="vertical" >


                <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lvSavedPNR"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </ListView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

][1]

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YScA.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu should not specify the layout height of "wrap_content" for the weighted children - do it like this for both children:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
```